# Symmetry, translations and reflections.

Tags: geometry, functions

a)Prove the symmetry with respect to the x-axis, the y-axis and the origin for the function "reference".

b)Calculate the domain of the function f (x) and the points of intersection with the axes.

c)Graph the function using symmetry, translations and reflections.

$$\begin{aligned}
& f(x)=(-x+1)^2+2, \quad f(x)=\frac{(x-2)^3}{2}-1, \quad f(x)=-\sqrt{x^2-4}+2 \\
& f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}-2, \quad f(x)=-\frac{|x-3|}{2}, \quad f(x)=-\frac{x}{3}+3 . \\
&
\end{aligned}$$

I tried the symmetry of $$f(x)=(-x+1)^2+2$$
the problem is that $$f(x) \neq f(-x), -f(x) \neq f(x) \,\,\,and\,\, -f(x) \neq f(-x) $$
But i know that is symmetric because it´s a cuadratic function.

it is possible to analyze the function only with x^2?

Comment: It is symmetric about the line $x = 1$ but you are correct, none of the symmetries as described in a).  Most of the functions have some axis / point of symmetry, but only one has a symmetry described in a).  While not clear, I suspect your teacher wants you to discuss the symmetries of $y=x^2$ and then the transformations (translations and dilation or compression) to get to the functions listed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you are only expected to examine a few specific types of symmetric in your question.

Even though it is not requested in your question, if you are interested in examining that it is is symmetric about the line $x=1$.

Verify that $f(1+x)=f(1-x)$ instead.

Now, we have \begin{align}
f(1+x)&=(-(1+x)+1)^2+2 \\
&=x^2+2 \\
f(1-x)&=(-(1-x)+1)^2+2 \\
&=x^2+2=f(1+x)
\end{align}

If the line of symmetry is $x=s$, then we check $f(s+x)=f(s-x)$.

Note that verifying $f(x)=f(-x)$ is a special case of checking the symmetry along the line of symmetry of $x=0$. Upon the transformation, the axis of symmetry would have been shifted as well.